# ag-grid select all doesn't select the all the rows in the grid with paging

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

With ag-grid 23v. I'm trying to add a header checkbox to the checkbox column (just checkboxes). I set the coldef to `checkboxselection= true and` header checkbox selection to true. But on select all only the rows in the current page gets selected . Is there a event fired on selectall which i could use to set all the rows in all the pages as selected.
I'm using
ag-grid : 23v on angualr: 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Even in pagination mode, the header checkbox selects all rows by default.

You can check this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/0OpGKZZsJrd543mY)

It prints the no. of rows selected in console on row selection.

```
  onSelectionChanged(params){
  console.log("No of rows selected :" + params.api.getSelectedRows().length);
}
```

You will notice that header checkbox selection will select all rows across all pages

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I see what you are saying but in my case Im using ag-grid my old angularjs app and I grab only page size rows from the server and also the total count so that I can do pagination. On next page i grab the next pagesize rows . Thus, 'select all' just looks for rowdata and selects only those rows which in my case is pagesize . Thus Im looking for if there is an event which gets fired on select all so I can do some custom selection and make it so that user selected all.

Comment: I mean I dont have all the rows in memory